# cvLoadImage fail in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone:
I tried to load a static image in ROS:
here is the part of code:
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

```
       int main (int argc, char** argv) {
       ...........................
       if( ! cvLoadImage("13_45_07-65.bmp") ) cout << "sorry" << endl;
      ............................
       }
 
 in the log file, I can find a " sorry ", which means the image is not successfully loaded.
 
 the code works well outside ros. I put it in ROS because I need the images to tell when to send geometry_msg.

 I use ROS electric and configure OpenCV-2.3.1 according to http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2.  
 OpenCV is used with ROS as a rosdep system dependency      

 I put the followings in the CMakeLists.txt of the package the code is in.
 "  find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

if(OpenCV_FOUND)
message("====== Found ${OpenCV_VERSION} =======")
 message("=== ${OpenCV_LIBS}======")
endif(OpenCV_FOUND) "

the cmake .. returns:
====== Found 2.3.1 =======
=== opencv_gpu;opencv_contrib;opencv_legacy;opencv_objdetect;opencv_calib3d;opencv_features2d;opencv_video;opencv_highgui;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_flann;opencv_core======

I have no idea why this simple OpenCV command in my code cannot be executed in ROS.  Anyone can help me?
Thank you in advance.

Yucong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31491/cvloadimage-fail-in-ros./) by [yclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2148/yclin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The program is probably executed with a different working directory than you expect, so the image file cannot be found. AFAIK `rosrun` keeps the current working directory, while `roslaunch` changes to some entirely different place. Neither changes the working directory to the package directory.

Current best practice is to use the `$(find foo)` directive in the launch file to substitute the absolute path to the package `foo` in a configuration value.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-09**:
roslaunch is going (usually) going to run in ~/.ros, unless you change some environment variables.

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-04-09**:
I think it does, but I have never read any official specification about that, so you probably should not rely on it.

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2012-10-15**:
hello, I want to load one image in some folder (with cvLoadImage), What must I do to tell roslaunch to search in the correct folder? I try moving the image to ./ros and works very well but I want put in other folder. How?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would vote for the includes, and the C-style function.

```
#include <highgui.h> 
#include <cv.h>
```

With these I'm not sure that you'll get what you need. The right way to do the includes is

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Those includes above will reference to the old legacy versions of opencv still available in some Ubuntu versions.

Also if you are developing a new code (and I can see that it's C++) please use the new C++ API to easily avoid problems like memory leaks and such.
Too bad that 95% of the example materials that can be found (official&unofficial) on OpenCV are still advertising the old API.
For example your line of code would look like this:

```
if( cv::imread("13_45_07-65.bmp").empty() )
    cout << "sorry" << endl;
```

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-04-10**:
Shouldn't this be 'if (cv::imread("13_45_07-65.bmp").empty())'? I am not sure what "!" does on cv::Mat...

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-04-11**:
fixed, thx

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-04-11**:
...no... you should print "yeah" istead of "sorry" when image loading succeeds ;-)

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-04-11**:
:) modified it in a pessimist way